# If $f(0) > 0$, show that $f(x) > 0$ on some open interval $(−a, a)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous function that maps $\mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Let $0<\epsilon<\frac{f(0)}{2}$ and let $a$ be such that for all $x$ with $\vert x-0\vert<a$ we have $\vert f(x)-f(0)\vert <\epsilon$ (such an $a$ is guaranteed to exist because $f$ is coninous at $0$). Now this implies that for $x\in(-a,a)$ it holds that $f(x)>f(0)-\epsilon>\frac{f(0)}{2}.$

Comment: Please don't answer junk posts.

Comment: @Nij What determines a junk post?

Comment: For example, writing a very unclear title and putting a single phrase in the body.